# how to add currency switcher dropdown in magento2 custom header

Tags: magento2, theme, custom, currency, header

I created custom header using below link.
http://oxsoftwares.com/add-custom-header-in-custom-theme-magento2/

I want to add currency switcher inside the custom header, how can we call currency switcher inside custom header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add following code into your `default.xml` file.

```
<referenceBlock name="custom_header">
     <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="currency" before="-" template="currency.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

And add below code into your `customheader.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency'); ?>
```

Comment: hi, in which path template file currency.phtml to be included?